# Adding 'count' in MySQL query with multiple tables in 'from' clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
select * from u, s, c, ut, m
```

which works fine, displaying all columns of all tables.  I want to add record counts to only the `u` table.

I tried this:

```
select (select count(*) as totalcount from u), * from u, s, c, ut, m
```

but it is throwing an error.

Comment: If an error is thrown then post the error message.

Comment: You should ask your question with a real world example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is working for me :

```
select * , (select count(*) from u) as totalcount from u , s , c , ut , m ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT t1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t3)  AS TotalCount FROM table_Name1 t1, tableName t`;

This might help you.
Specify the column from which table you want to retrieve. And if you want all columns better way is to `join` the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select count(*) as totalcount from u), * from u, s, c, ut, m
```

I try your query and it works fine . Just try this . I hope it works.

```
select (select count(*) from u) as totalcount, * from u, s, c, ut, m
```